# How to populate the TableLayout with ImageView dynamically in android jdk?

Tags: java, android

I've a `TableLayout` element in my `main.xml`:

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableLayout>
```

I don't want to hardcode the `ImageView` in `main.xml`.

How to embed the `ImageView` in `.java` ?

Comment: You may take a look at one of the tutorials on the Android Developers official site, specifically this one: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html. It uses a `GridView` rather than a `TableLayout`, but shows how to pick images and populate `ImageView` instances in Java code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
            TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
            for (int r=1; r<=rowCount; r++){
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                for (int c=1; c<=columnCount; c++){
                    ImageView im = new ImageView (this);
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_name));
                    im.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0); //padding in each image if needed
                    //add here on click event etc for each image...
                    //...
                    tr.addView(im, imageWidth,imageHeight); 
                }
                table.addView(tr);
            }
```