# How do I set up non-scrolling lists?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to produce an activity with an interface somewhat like that of the 'add contact' activity in the standard people application - ie something with a number of lists (email addresses, phone numbers, etc) each of which has a variable number of entries and an 'add' button. The lists themselves don't scroll (ie all entries are shown all of the time), but the overall interface does scroll.

My first attempt uses several listviews inside a linearlayout inside a scrollview; the code adds elements to the listviews as required. However, I cannot find a way to prevent the lists from being scrolled, rather than being shown full length.

Can anyone suggest how I might stop the listviews from scrolling ? Or perhaps suggest a better container than the listview (I don't want to re-invent the wheel) ?

Thanks,
    Richard

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using table view instead? It should be possible to make rows clickable. Here is how to create table rows in code in my other answer:
[How to populate the TableLayout with ImageView dynamically in android jdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665853/how-to-populate-the-tablelayout-with-imageview-dynamically-in-android-jdk/4675013#4675013)

Comment: TableLayout doesn't seem to have any way of removing rows, so isn't suitable, I think.

Comment: That should be possible with row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row); table.removeView(row); But you would have to store row id within the Tag of some view in the row or the row itself so that onClick knows which row was selected...

Comment: Oops, I forgot to look at inherited methods. I'm not sure about sorting entries though, but maybe I'm not too worried about that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ExpandableListView will be more helpfull here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html for more info

Comment: I looked at those, but my lists are not multilevel (and since it inherits from listview, I would assume that the scrolling behaviour is the same).

Answer (score 0):

> The lists themselves don't scroll (ie all entries are shown all of the time), but the overall interface does scroll.

This is incorrect. All entries are not shown all of the time.

> My first attempt uses several listviews inside a linearlayout inside a scrollview

You cannot put a `ListView` in a `ScrollView`.

> Or perhaps suggest a better container than the listview (I don't want to re-invent the wheel) ?

The add-a-contact activity uses [a `ScrollView` wrapped around a `LinearLayout`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=res/layout/act_edit.xml;h=2a7171724857c00b30946e939b7844e8120486fd;hb=HEAD) holding each of the "editors".