# Set Imageview Height And Width Programmatically

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            TableRow row =new TableRow(this);
            View v = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
            TextView tv_main =new TextView(this);
            ImageView iv = new imageView(this);                              
            tv_main.setText("Test");                
            iv.setImageDrawable(v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon));
            row.addView(iv);
            row.addView(tv_main);
            table_layout.addView(row);
    }
```

How to set height and width programmatically? I had tried

```
iv.getLayoutParams().height=80;
iv.getLayoutParams().width=100;
```

but image is not display.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665853/how-to-populate-the-tablelayout-with-imageview-dynamically-in-android-jdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new `LayoutParams` object and set the height and width for it and then pass it to the iv.setLayoutParams() method.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(100, 80); 
iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: This is also not working                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(120, 80));
iv.setLayoutParams(lp) ;

Comment: I see you are adding the ImageView to a table row so please try to replace  LinearLayout.LayoutParams with TableRow.LayoutParams. The child params should follow the parent type.

Comment: i need 15 reputation to vote ..currently i have only 4

Comment: You can accept an answer for your questions on the left :)